# How to solve Acumatica SQL Error After Upgrade

Tags: sql-server, acumatica, erp

I'm trying to update my client's Acumatica ERP to the latest version. I cloned the current instance to test drive the update procedure and make sure everything runs smoothly. They are currently using version 2019 R2 and want to update to 2020 R2.

Using the test instance, I updated it to the latest build of 2020 R2 and everything seems to be working except for one report. When I try to generate the Report I'm getting the following error.

[image]

I imagine this has to do with a change in the Database. However I can't find a table with that name either in the new database or in the current database. I'm not sure if that's table, store procedure, view, etc. I'm not very familiar with SQL.

I loaded the report in the report designer and try looking at the schema but couldn't find any reference to that particular table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

CES

Answer (score 1):

The `SOAdjus`t table must exist in the database.

Please, try again with the following steps:

1. Create a snapshot of the client system.
2. Create a new system on the same version
3. Download and restore the snapshot created on the 1 point.
4. Download and install Acumatica 2020R2 ERP Configuration
5. Open the Acumatica ERP Configuration.
6. Select the system
7. For the upgrade procedure
   7.1 Click the **Update Only Database**
   7.2 Click the **Update Only Website**

In Acumatica 2019R2, the `SOAdjust` table is in two different namespaces.

1. `PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry.SOAdjust`
2. `PX.Objects.SO.SOAdjust`

In Acumatica 2020R2, the `SOAdjust` table is in only one of them

1. `PX.Objects.SO.SOAdjust`

*I think you should update the `SOAdjust` table in the report.*

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick reply. How can I view the namespaces in SQL Management Studio? I checked and the SOAdjust table does exists on both DB. If I go into the table properties under schema it shows as dbo.

Answer (score 0):

"view the namespaces in SQL Management Studio" - You don't.  Namespaces are from .Net, and have to do with the code organization (crude description, but close enough for understanding).  At a SQL level, the Acumatica structure is quite flat, just tables in the database (VERY few fancy sql tricks / sql level organization), all the "Real" logic tends to be in the business objects (Graphs, for the most part, though some interesting logic is within the DAC (data object classes))